# Is ther an audit log feature in Azure?

Tags: azure

I want to be able to create an audit log to monitor who changes what in Azure. To the point that if someone changes a config setting then it will log that this user change this setting . Is there a feature in Azure that i can enable and download the log ?

If i do the following:

```
az monitor activity-log list
    --subscription <subscription_id>
    --query '[].{Time: eventTimestamp, Resource: resourceGroupName, Operation: operationName, Description: description}'
    --output table > activity_log.txt
```

It only outputs Time and Resource ad not all the activity for the past week or 1month or what ever time frame i give.

Any one know how i can do this and return all columns for the past 3months lets say , with any data that has been changed  ?

Comment: The `activity-log` is exactly what you're after - but it should return almost all details - can you be more specific about the data you're expecting but not seeing?

Comment: Yes, Azure has an audit log feature called query auditing. Query auditing is enabled with a diagnostic setting on the Log Analytics workspace. This allows you to send audit data to the current workspace or any other workspace in your subscription, to Azure Event Hubs to send outside of Azure, or to Azure Storage for archiving. To enable query auditing, you can access the diagnostic setting for a Log Analytics workspace in the Azure portal from either the Azure Monitor menu or the Log Analytics workspaces menu.

Comment: Once enabled, audit logs provide telemetry about log queries run in Azure Monitor, including information such as when a query was run, who ran it, what tool was used, the query text, and performance statistics describing the query's execution. You can then use Azure Monitor logs to write complex queries and logic, integrate with alerts, Power BI, and other tools, save data for longer retention periods, and cross-reference with other logs such as security, virtual machine, and custom.

Comment: To answer your second question, you can use the Azure CLI command az monitor activity-log list to retrieve activity logs for the past week or month. However, it only outputs Time and Resource by default. To return all columns for the past three months, you can add the --offset parameter with a value of -P3M to specify a time range of the past three months. You can also add the --query parameter to specify which columns you want to output.

Comment: Kindly try this and let me know- `az monitor activity-log list
    --subscription <subscription_id>
    --offset -P3M
    --query '[].{Time: eventTimestamp, Resource: resourceGroupName, Operation: operationName, Description: description}'
    --output table > activity_log.txt`

Comment: gives an error:   az : ERROR: argument --offset: expected one argument

Answer (score 0):

> Any one know how i can do this and return all columns for the past 3months lets say , with any data that has been changed ?

Azure Activity Log is an example of *structured logging*, where each log-item is a (JSON) data structure consisting of lists and nested objects, where the schema/design of the objects varies, rather than being like CSV where every log-item has an identical tabular structure  and every row always shares the exact same columns.

...because using CSV for something like this would be silly as log-entries are very hetereogenous: it would be impossible to represent a log-entry for changing a database's performance tier *and* another log-entry for shutting down an AppService website in the same log file, because the two events wouldn't share the columns in common (unless you don't mind `NULL`s everywhere...)

---

**Anyway...**

[The per-event data is inside the `properties` property, which you'll neeed to explicitly select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/activity-log?view=azure-cli-latest) with `--select`.

You'll also need to specify `caller` to get info about the user that performed the action.

Furthermore, you'll also probably want `submissionTimestamp resourceProviderName resourceType  operationName` in addition, so you end-up with:

```
az monitor activity-log list
    --subscription <subscription_id>
    --select select submissionTimestamp resourceProviderName resourceType  operationName caller properties
    --output table > activity_log.json
```

When I run it, I get a lot of info I don't care about, but the details I want are there, just somewhat buried.

For example, in the couple-of-megabytes of activity logs I downloaded by running that command, it has the details of an Azure SQL tier-change request I submitted about 5 hours ago:

```
{
    "category": {
        "localizedValue": "Administrative",
        "value": "Administrative"
    },
    "id": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/<subscriptionId>/RESOURCEGROUPS/RESGROUP-POOP/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.SQL/SERVERS/LIFEISSHORTANDLOVEISALWAYSOVERINTHEMORNING/DATABASES/INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET/events/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/ticks/638435579706689870",
    "operationName": {
        "localizedValue": "Update SQL database",
        "value": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write"
    },
    "properties": {
        "Caller": "live.com#___@outlook.com",
        "CallerCredentialType": "LiveId",
        "CorrelationId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "Description_scrubbed": "Update SQL Database INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET on Server LIFEISSHORTANDLOVEISALWAYSOVERINTHEMORNING: Change database name from 'INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET' to 'INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET'. Change edition from 'S3' to 'S6'. ",
        "EventChannel": "OperationLogStore",
        "EventId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "EventName": "UpdateDatabase",
        "EventProperties": "{\"ServerName\":\"LIFEISSHORTANDLOVEISALWAYSOVERINTHEMORNING\",\"Description\":\"Update SQL Database INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET on Server LIFEISSHORTANDLOVEISALWAYSOVERINTHEMORNING: Change database name from 'INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET' to 'INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET'. Change edition from 'S3' to 'S6'. \",\"ClientIp\":\"123.456.789.123\",\"ApplicationName\":null,\"StepName\":null,\"StepOrder\":null,\"TotalStepsNumber\":null}",
        "EventSource": "SQL Databases Event Supplier",
        "IpAddress": "123.456.789.123",
        "OperationName": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases/write",
        "Status": "Started",
        "originalEventTimestamp": "2/15/2024 1:39:02 AM"
    },
    "resourceGroup": "RESGROUP-POOP",
    "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/<subscriptionId>/RESOURCEGROUPS/RESGROUP-POOP/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.SQL/SERVERS/LIFEISSHORTANDLOVEISALWAYSOVERINTHEMORNING/DATABASES/INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET",
    "resourceProviderName": {
        "localizedValue": "Microsoft SQL",
        "value": "MICROSOFT.SQL"
    },
    "resourceType": {
        "localizedValue": "MICROSOFT.SQL/servers/databases",
        "value": "MICROSOFT.SQL/servers/databases"
    },
    "submissionTimestamp": "2024-02-15T01:39:30.668987Z"
}
```

The gubbins is in the double-encoded `"EventProperties"` property, [which can be unescaped](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) out to:

```
{
    "ServerName": "LIFEISSHORTANDLOVEISALWAYSOVERINTHEMORNING",
    "Description": "Update SQL Database INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET on Server LIFEISSHORTANDLOVEISALWAYSOVERINTHEMORNING: Change database name from 'INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET' to 'INEEDALLTHELOVEICANGET'. Change edition from 'S3' to 'S6'. ",
    "ClientIp": "123.456.789.123",
    "ApplicationName": null,
    "StepName": null,
    "StepOrder": null,
    "TotalStepsNumber": null
}
```